# R readxl multiple classes

Tags: r

I'm trying to read in a xlsx file using the below script.  The problem I'm running into is that when it reads it in and I look at the str() I see, "Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   271 obs. of  109 variables:".  Then, when I run head(x) it looks like it's creating a tibble for each individual variable.  Is there another way I should read in the excel or an argument I'm missing?  All I want is to read in the excel and save it as a dataframe.

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(readxl)

x <- read_excel("workbook.xlsx")

>class(head(x))
>"tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Also, I read in the entire tidyverse due to a tutorial I was reading (following blindly to see where it would bring me).  I'm not able to display my output due to my privacy, but when I run str(x) the output looks like a regular str() function with, num, chr, POSIXct (for dates which I don't really want, but don't see an issue with), etc.  When I run head(x) or just x I get the same display of, "# A tibble: 271 x 109" and the first 10 rows of the first 6 columns, and then, " ... with 261 more rows, and 102 more variables: " with the list of the rest of my header names.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "it's creating a tiddle for each individual variable".

Comment: Why are you doing `install.packages("tidyverse")` when you just want to read an excel file?

Comment: Please also show the console output of `str(x)` and `head(x)`

Comment: Is having it as a tibble even such a big deal? Reading an xlsx file will automatically have the dataset loaded in with 3 classes. `tbl_df, tbl   
 and data.frame`

Comment: Maybe you want to do `class(x) <- 'data.frame'`?

Comment: Or `x <- as.data.frame(x)`

Comment: Yep, Rob & Rich it was that simple.  Thank y'all

Answer (score 0):

An excel file read via `readxl::read_excel()` is already a data frame and does not always need to be coerced to be treated as a data frame. The output from `class()` is an inheritance tree. In the OP example, `x` is a `tbl_df` which inherits from `tbl` which inherits from `data.frame`.

This can be confirmed with the `is.data.frame()` function as follows.

We'll generate random data and write it to an Excel file on disk. Then, we'll read it with `readxl::read_excel()` and validate it with `is.data.frame()`.

First, the write...

```
library(writexl)
data <- data.frame(matrix(runif(100),nrow=10,ncol=10))
write_xlsx(data,"./data/simpleExcel.xlsx")
```

Second, the read and validate steps

```
library(readxl)
theData <- read_excel("./data/simpleExcel.xlsx")
class(theData)
is.data.frame(theData)
```

...and the output.

```
> library(writexl)
> data <- data.frame(matrix(runif(100),nrow=10,ncol=10))
> write_xlsx(data,"./data/simpleExcel.xlsx")
[1] "/Users/lgreski/gitrepos/datascience/data/simpleExcel.xlsx"
> library(readxl)
> theData <- read_excel("./data/simpleExcel.xlsx")
> class(theData)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> is.data.frame(theData)
[1] TRUE
>
```

Now, if you want to override the `tbl` specific behavior of `head()` when printing the header of the data frame, you will need to coerce the object with `as.data.frame()`.

```
head(as.data.frame(theData))
```

...and the output:

```
> head(as.data.frame(theData))
          X1        X2        X3        X4         X5         X6         X7
1 0.86096810 0.2323373 0.9913265 0.8533702 0.09094279 0.54396940 0.87441769
2 0.09762566 0.9126343 0.4528663 0.9223295 0.02801973 0.11576152 0.64557643
3 0.82491603 0.4988662 0.8027047 0.8490365 0.01687182 0.38767569 0.67800481
4 0.82016269 0.5148852 0.2248160 0.8339404 0.49346620 0.07940575 0.08192492
5 0.34181443 0.3943045 0.2749949 0.9736331 0.76965589 0.30493388 0.82205653
6 0.83387527 0.5539088 0.2977256 0.7804322 0.61297012 0.74456391 0.88700870
          X8         X9        X10
1 0.01152920 0.83665797 0.63328141
2 0.66086545 0.65325452 0.30709237
3 0.89277291 0.08738481 0.71723959
4 0.01893088 0.87709515 0.32186587
5 0.80091302 0.09594028 0.88764437
6 0.02912132 0.29151880 0.06874472
>
```